# Methodology to debug tcdrain() blocking indefinitely

Tags: c++, serial-port, blocking, termios

I'm sending packets from an Ubuntu machine to an STM32 autopilot through a USB cable using `write()` and `tcdrain()`:

```
int Serial_port::_write_port(char* buff, unsigned int len) {
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex_write_on_port);
    const int bytes_written = static_cast<int>(write(_fd,buff, len));
    if(bytes_written<0) {
        printf("write to port failed with errno: %s\n", std::strerror(errno));
    }
    //wait until all data has been written to the port
    tcdrain(_fd);
    return bytes_written;
}
```

After a few thousands packets successfully sent, `tcdrain()` randomly blocks. I'm trying to understand why.

Any recommendations on how to debug this?

I've done some research but couldn't come across a good debug methodology.
Note: I've noticed if I run a simple python command in another terminal `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttySAC0')` this "unfreezes" my code about 75% of the time but I'm kind of at a loss to understand why.

If that helps, here is how I configure the port:

```
int Serial_port::_config_port() {
    //Config based on following sources:
    //https://github.com/mavlink/c_uart_interface_example
    //https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/linux-serial-ports-using-c-cpp/
    struct termios config;
    if(tcgetattr(_fd, &config) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Input flags - Turn off input processing
    // convert break to null byte, no CR to NL translation,
    // no NL to CR translation, don't mark parity errors or breaks
    // no input parity check, don't strip high bit off,
    // no XON/XOFF software flow control
    config.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | ICRNL | INLCR | PARMRK | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);

    // Output flags - Turn off output processing
    // no CR to NL translation, no NL to CR-NL translation,
    // no NL to CR translation, no column 0 CR suppression,
    // no Ctrl-D suppression, no fill characters, no case mapping,
    // no local output processing
    config.c_oflag &= ~(OCRNL | ONLCR | ONLRET | ONOCR | OFILL | OPOST);

    // No line processing:
    // echo off, echo newline off, canonical mode off,
    // extended input processing off, signal chars off
    config.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);

    // Turn off character processing
    // clear current char size mask, no parity checking,
    // no output processing, force 8 bit input
    config.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB | CSTOPB); //~CSTOPB to set only 1 stop bit for multiflex
    config.c_cflag |= CS8;

    // One input byte is enough to return from read()
    // Inter-character timer off
    config.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0; //DEBUG: this is different from mavlink recommended setup. Confirm this is ok
    config.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

    //baudrate
    if(cfsetispeed(&config,_baudrate)<0) return -1; //input baudrate
    if(cfsetospeed(&config,_baudrate)<0) return -1; //output baudrate

    //write config to port
    if(tcsetattr(_fd,TCSAFLUSH,&config) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout<<"port "<<_uart_name<< " configured successfully"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"through a USB cable"* -- That's ambiguous.  Are you using a USB-serial adapter or CDC ACM?  How do you open the serial terminal, blocking or nonblocking mode?  Your termios configuration neither enables nor disables HW and SW flow-control.  It is left to chance whether any flow-control is active or not. Flow-control could cause the symptom you describe.  IOW your termios configuration is incomplete.

Comment: There is no USB-serial adapter, just a USB cable connecting the Ubuntu machine to the autopilot. The port is open in blocking mode '    fd = open(port, O_RDWR);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);   ' . Thanks for the suggestion on flow control, I hadn't noticed it wasn't set in the output flags.